# Python regex: Why re.sub('a*', '-', 'abxd',count=1) = '-bxd' ? Shouldn't it be '-abxd'?

Tags: python, regex, regular-language

after reading the documentation for `re` package for python. I think that the result should be `re.sub('a*', '-', 'abxd',count=1) -> '-abxd'` . However, I get the following results:

```
re.sub('a*', '-', 'abxd',count=1) -> '-bxd'
```

It really confuses me as the first match should be the empty match in front of `'a'` in `'abxd'`.

In particular, I try three other examples and I get the expected results as follow:

```
re.sub('a*', '-', '  abxd',count=1) -> '-  abxd'

re.sub('a*', '-', ' abxd',count=1) -> '- abxd'

re.sub('x*', '-', ' abxd',count=1) -> '-abxd'
```

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Regex's are greedy. The greediest match is to match the `a` without backtracking. The `*` does mean 0 or more so your interpretation is correct for the NEXT match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what `findall` does with your example:

```
>>> re.findall(r'(a*)', 'abcd')
['a', '', '', '', '']
```

Five matches, the first being the easiest and most obvious: match the `a`. The next being *0 or more* which matches at each character boundary:

```
for i in range(len(re.findall(r'a*', 'abcd'))):
    s_sub=re.sub(r'a*', '-', 'abcd', count=i+1)
    print(f' sub {i+1}: {s_sub}')
```

Prints:

```
sub 1: -bcd
sub 2: --bcd
sub 3: --b-cd
sub 4: --b-c-d
sub 5: --b-c-d-
```

And if you think about it, this is the right way to do it.

If you had `re.sub('a*', '-', 'aaaabxd',count=1)` would you expect:

1. the first match to be to insert `-` into the character boundary at the beginning of the string to get `'-aaabxd'` or
2. after the `a`'s to get `'aaa-bxd'` or
3. would you expect `a*` to mean as many a's as possible to result in `'-bxd'`?

The third option is what you get with `a*`:

```
>>> re.sub('a*', '-', 'aaaabxd',count=1)
'-bxd'
```

This behavior is the result of the [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html) `*` being GREEDY.
There is a meta character in the regex language that says *don't be greedy, be LAZY* when combined with a `+` or `*` quantifier which is `?`. If you use it, it results in the behavior that you are expecting since the first obvious match of matching all the `a`'s is skipped:

```
>>> re.sub('a*?', '-', 'aaaabxd',count=1)
'-aaaabxd'
```

And:

```
s='aabcd'
for i in range(len(re.findall(r'a*?', s))):
    s_sub=re.sub(r'a*?', '-', s, count=i+1)
    print(f'sub {i+1}: {s_sub}')
```

Prints:

```
sub 1: -aabcd
sub 2: --abcd
sub 3: ---abcd
sub 4: ----bcd
sub 5: -----bcd
sub 6: -----b-cd
sub 7: -----b-c-d
sub 8: -----b-c-d-
```

Answer (score 1):

`a*` matches *as many* copies of `a` as it can at the current position. It *can* match zero (unlike `a+`), but if there are any there, it will match all of them.

Comment: Thank you! match as many as it can at the current position.